# FGLS vs M estimator

Tags: econometrics, heteroscedasticity, sas, weighted-regression

I have been reading a lot that in Robust Regression, there are 2 ways of handling heteroskedasticity. 1)WLS - In SAS PROC ROBUST procedure, M estimator and Iteratively Reweighted Least Square. 2) FGLS - Estimating the weight needed to achieve homoskedasticity. My experience is that in industry, I rarely see people using FGLS. Is there a reason why M estimator is better than the other one?

Thanks.